# can't create dependence of msqlconnector in pom.xml in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I can't create the dependency for `mysql` in `eclipse`.

> error Missing artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.7.9

I use maven console to create the dependency, but It doesn't work
What can I do??

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is because the current version in 5.* series is 5.1.40.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.40</version>
</dependency>
```

There is no version 5.7.9. You can check current version [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) or all available [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).